# Windows Theme Issues

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, themes

So I was recently fiddling with my theme settings on my computer and accidentally changed the theme. Now the top bar of chrome (where extra tabs would go) is blue instead of transparent. The bottom bar where active programs are pinned is also no longer transparent. I tried changing the theme back, but nothing will work. I'm sure this is an extremely simple fix, but I have no idea what that fix is.

Edit: I have figured out that windows desktop manager wasn't enabled. After enabling the manager, Aero effects (apparently the transparent bars) worked. I still am unsure how this happened though. Any ideas?

Comment: Switch to an [Aero theme](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how+to+switch+to+an+aero+theme&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=axjhVa7TGozbuQTb64qgCg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two reasons it could have swapped. Firstly, Windows likes to swap the theme to Windows Basic when the GPU is running low on memory, but I doubt this was the case.

Whilst you were messing around with the themes, you probably clicked a basic theme.

You can swap to an Aero theme easily by right clicking on your desktop and hitting "personalise"

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to change the color/transparency:

1. Right click on the desktop
2. Click personalize
3. Click 'Window Color' down the bottom

Then you can play around with the color and transparency.
I hope this helps.